# ruby-regex: how to match for "/table[number]"?

Tags: ruby, regex

i want to match for all "/table[number]"

so strings like "/table[1]" and "/table" are matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon your needs, you may want to throw in word boundary markers as well. So

```
 /\b\/table(?:\[\d+\])?\b/
```

Without these the regex would match strings like
/tables
/tableTop
.....

Answer (score 2):

```
/\/table(?:\[\d+\])?/
```

Comment: This is definitely most of the solution, but I like Jasmeet's suggestion to also include word boundaries.